# Scheme function that takes two lists and computes how many times the pattern within the first list appears in the second list

Tags: list, math, pattern-matching, scheme

```
(define (pattern lis1 lis2)
    (cond ((null? lis1) 0)
        (( = (car lis1) lis2) ( + 1 (pattern (cdr lis1) lis2)))
        (else (pattern (cdr lis1) lis2))))
```

This is what I have so far but when I run this I receive the error "=: expects a number as 2nd argument, given 'a" when I enter
(pattern '(a a) '(a a a a a a a))

Comment: What did you pass it as parameters?

Comment: `=` is for comparing numbers, and you're trying to compare `'a` to a list. You also seem a bit confused about which parameter is the pattern you're looking for. (A more informative naming convention would help.)

Comment: Hint: start with writing a function that determines whether one list is the first part of another list.